# Rebuild indexes on replication server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 1 live server and 1 replication server. For reporting purpose we use the replication server and on the replication server we have created an index. So I want to know if I rebuild my index on replication server or do I have to remove the replication server first and then rebuild the index or can I directly rebuild the indexes on replication server?

Answer (score 2):

According to [official advice from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151740(v=sql.105).aspx) there is no need to remove the subscriber.

> **How do I rebuild indexes or tables in replicated databases?**
>
> There are a variety of mechanisms for rebuilding indexes. They can all be used with no special considerations for replication, with the following exception: primary keys are required on tables in transactional publications, so you cannot drop and recreate primary keys on these tables.
>
> **How do I add or change indexes on publication and subscription databases?**
>
> Indexes can be added at the Publisher or Subscribers with no special considerations for replication (be aware that indexes can affect performance). CREATE INDEX and ALTER INDEX are not replicated, so if you add or change an index at, for example, the Publisher, you must make the same addition or change at the Subscriber if you want it reflected there.

There is a potential, AFAIK, if you're using transactional replication that you will get a big queue of transactions that can't be applied to your subscriber (assuming that your publisher is quite busy otherwise you wouldn't be using replication). This may need to be managed, possibly by doing a `REORGANIZE` instead of a `REBUILD` or some such, but you can gauge that best for your situation.

Comment: "There are a variety of mechanisms for rebuilding indexes. They can all be used with no special considerations for replication, with the following exception: primary keys are required on tables in transactional publications, so you cannot drop and recreate primary keys on these tables." Disagree with this as I have a system in which replication was breaking weekly due to a standard maintenance plan for index and stats rebuild. Turned this one job off and it hasn't broken since. Definitely need some considerations when it comes to the size of the table and frequency data is written.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming that the data within the tables are changing, yes, you'll need to maintain the indexes on  each DB. You'll also need to set up maintenance for the statistics as well.

Comment: How do you explain this? I'm asking because it contradicts the previous answer which references official Microsoft documentation? Is there any reference material that supports your answer?

Comment: I don't see a contradiction. First of all: Nothing "forces" us to defrag, we never "have" to do that. You could argue that with modern disk-subsysten, it is a waste of time. Setting that aside, the quote above clearly states that ALTER INDEX isn't replicated. So, if you want the defrag to be performed at the subscriber, then you would schedule such a job there as well.